# Get color display profile in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to get color display (RGB, sRGB,etc) and display gamma from web browser using Javascript? I am developing an application that need to have consistent color.

Comment: no, but you could make short calibration routine where they click the box that looks best to them...

Comment: Do you want to calculate these for an image, or for the contents of the page?

Comment: I want to calculate this for an image.

Answer (score -1):

No. This data is not exposed to the browser, and is not available at all on many user agents. (That is, many web browsers run on devices that do not implement any form of color correction.)